# Adding customize font to Google Script App

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I'm developing a web app that requires a certain type of font used by my company. Since I'm using Google Apps Script, I uploaded the font files to a google drive folder. But it's not working. In the script, the `https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX` is the shareable link. I tried to use `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=` but it didn't work too.

I'll be very grateful if anyone can help. Thanks!

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'specials';
    src: url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/specials.eot');
    src: url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/specials.eot') format("embedded-opentype"),
      url("https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/specials.otf") format("opentype"),
      url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/specials.woff') format("woff"),
      url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/specials.woff2') format("woff2"),
      url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/specials.ttf') format("truetype"),
      url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/specials.svg') format("svg"); 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1{
  font-family: 'specials', Georgia,'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

**Update**

It is as @Tanaike suggested, the right way to do it is to use this link `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###` for all the different formats of the font files. It appeared to not be working at first because I missed out two.

Here's the corrected CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'specials';
    src: url('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###');
    src: url('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###') format("embedded-opentype"),
      url("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###") format("opentype"),
      url('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###') format("woff"),
      url('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###') format("woff2"),
      url('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###') format("truetype"),
      url('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###') format("svg"); 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that in your script, it is required to modify the URL. So, how about the following URL?

#### From:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/###
```

- From your this URL, I guessed that `XXX` might be the file ID of the file.

#### To:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###
```

or, if the above URL cannot be used, please use the following URL.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###
```

- In this case, please use your API key. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)
- Please replace `###fileId###` with your file ID.
- Please replace `###your API key###` with your API key.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your files on Google Drive have already been publicly shared. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads)
- [Using API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but both didn't work for me. I'm not too sure about the API key. Is it right that I just have to create a project, go to credentials and select API keys? I followed these steps from Google and got a key. It still didn't work though.

Comment: @LauraEverdeen Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `but both didn't work for me. I'm not too sure about the API key. Is it right that I just have to create a project, go to credentials and select API keys? I followed these steps from Google and got a key. It still didn't work though.`, in this case, when you have your API key, please use it to `###your API key###` of `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###`. Please replace `###your API key###` with your API key, and test it again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I created an API key and inserted it in `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###` but it still didn't work. I have checked the `###fileId###`, and it is set at open to anyone who has the link. Any idea why the font still can't load?

Comment: @LauraEverdeen Thank you for replying. About `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###`, for example, when you directly access your URL using your browser, what result will you obtain? Because, when an error occurs, you can see the error message by this. And, I thought that when an error occurs, you can confirm the reason for the error.

Comment: @LauraEverdeen Now, I thought I might notice the reason for your issue. This URL uses Drive API. So, for example, when Drive API is not enabled and access to your URL using browser, an error like `"reason": "accessNotConfigured"` occurs. In that case, please access to the URL of `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview?project=###` of `"extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview?project=###"`. And, enable Drive API, and test it again. If this was not the direct solution to your current issue, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. When I tried to access `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key###` directly on browser, there was the error `like "reason": "accessNotConfigured"` as you said. Then I enabled the Drive API and tried the link again. A file with the file name of `###fileId###` downloaded automatically to my device. I deployed my web app, but the font still couldn't load.

Comment: @LauraEverdeen Thank you for replying. From `When I tried to access https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?alt=media&key=###your API key### directly on browser, there was the error like "reason": "accessNotConfigured" as you said. Then I enabled the Drive API and tried the link again. A file with the file name of ###fileId### downloaded automatically to my device.`, in this case, it is indicated that the file can be downloaded using the API key.

Comment: @LauraEverdeen About `I deployed my web app, but the font still couldn't load.`, unfortunately, when I tested this, the font can be loaded and the text with the loaded font can be seen. So, I cannot replicate your situation. I think that the reason that script worked fine is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you add your sample HTML for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @LauraEverdeen For example, when you redeployed your Web Apps as a new version and test it again, what result will you obtain? By the way, unfortunately, when I tested your showing CSS using my proposed URL, the loaded font can be used. I deeply apologize that I cannot replicate your situation of `I deployed my web app, but the font still couldn't load.`. So, I think that it is required to know the method for correctly replicating your issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I'm so sorry! I just went through my CSS and realized that I didn't put `?alt=media&key=` in two of the links. Once I corrected that, it works! Thank you so much for your patience and I'm again very sorry for taking up your time to re-test the codes.

Comment: @LauraEverdeen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.